# How to use requests.get while using a proxy server through ssr

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, vpn

I already brought a proxy server on SSR which has a password but I don't know how to set up a proxy server while I am using python's requests to access a website which is not accessible in my country.

My SSR version is ShadowsocksR-dotnet4.0,

and the server I brought is located in American

Python version is 3.6.8